# What are safe keys to remap in vim?

Tags: vim

So far I've been trying to use Vim in as vanilla a configuration as possible, so as to save myself hassle when moving between machines. However, there are a few things I'd really like to bind keys, such as to shorten `"_diwP` which I use often to delete the word under the cursor and replace it with one from the clipboard. Are there any particular keys that are conventionally reserved for user-defined mappings? The point of this question is mostly that I would like to avoid hassle later on when I decide to install some plugin or take my configuration files to vim on another OS and find that my key mappings clash with something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the letters are already taken:

<del>http://www.dc.turkuamk.fi/docs/soft/vim/vim_idx.html#vim_idx.html</del> (broken link)
http://web.archive.org/web/20091026182612/http://www.dc.turkuamk.fi/docs/soft/vim/vim_idx.html (web archive - HTML)
http://www.rpi.edu/dept/acm/packages/vim/4.2/sgi_62/lib/vim/vim_idx.txt (plaintext)

But if I want permenant commands I use `<leader>` as a prefix.

```
:map <leader>l    :list!
```

The default leader is '\' so by typing `\l` I can switch the state of list.
Note the leader can be changed. See `:help leader`

Note: to make sure I have my vim mapping available anytime I want them, I just put the .vimrc file on a convenient webserver. Then I can just use wget (or a browser) to get my .vimrc file at any time.

Answer (score 5):

***All keys are safe to remap in Vim.*** However, there are two types of mappings: ***recursive*** and ***non recursive***.

***a) Recursive:***

If you remap for example,

```
nmap x dd
```

*x deletes the line instead of one character*

you will have effectively lost the ***x*** key for future mappings, as well as overwritten the delete character function. Were sometime in the future some plugin depend on that key, that could present a problem.

For example,

```
nmap <C-x> xxx
```

will delete three lines instead of three characters, because it is effectively doing dddddd. This is a problem since effectively were some of your plugins to use the ***x*** (and they surely will) it will create problems (nasty ones).

***b) Non recursive mapping***

```
nnoremap x dd
```

solves that problem in a way that it will assign ***dd*** to ***x*** so that upon your pressing ***x*** you delete a line instead of a character, but any future mapping

```
nnoremap <C-x> xxx
```

will have the *original* ***x***  on the right hand side functionality.

***Always use nnoremap, inoremap ... the non-recursive mapping instead of nmap, imap and so on ... unless you have a very strong reason for doing the opposite.***

Answer (score 2):

I have a french keyboard. I use `é`, `è`, `à`, `ù`, `µ`, `§`, `£`, `ç` ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Alt Gr key, its REALLY useful for situations like this, since if you press it in combination with other letters you have a whole new alphabet available.

I use:

- Alt Gr + s (ß), for easyMotion search for letter;
- Alt Gr + y (←) to yank into the register q;
- Alt Gr + p (þ) to paste the content of the register q;
- and so on..